# Wampserver localhost opening wrong files?

Tags: wampserver

So, I'm trying to update my homepage for my school project, and I've made some noticeable changes in my html file, but when I open localhost, it shows the old ones.

Yes, I have tried saving, and it still opens the old ones. I tried emptying the www folder and putting the files back, but that doesn't work either.

I did notice that it's accepting the changes in css files, but it doesn't want to update html files.

Answer (score 0):

Might be cache problems. Just clear you browser cache and try.
Make sure you are putting the right file, sometime the file you are editing and the file you have in the server might be different.